# Pre-filter pivot data in Oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a dataset. I need to be able to filter the values going into the pivot, but the pivot itself will be part of a larger SELECT statement.

So, for instance:

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'ALUM' AS DONOR_CODE, 1 AS PRIORITY FROM DUAL
  UNION 
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'STAFF' AS DONOR_CODE, 2 AS PRIORITY FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 8 AS ID, 'ALUM' AS DONOR_CODE, 1 AS PRIORITY FROM DUAL
  UNION 
  SELECT 8 AS ID, 'ALMG' AS DONOR_CODE, 2 AS PRORITY FROM DUAL
  UNION 
  SELECT 8 AS ID, 'STAF' AS DONOR_CODE, 3 AS PRORITY FROM DUAL
)
, PIVOT_DATA AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM TEST_DATA
  PIVOT (MAX(DONOR_CODE) AS DONOR_CODE FOR PRIORITY IN (1,2,3)
  )
)
SELECT * FROM PIVOT_DATA;
```

returns...

```
 ID   1_DONOR_CODE  2_DONOR_CODE    3_DONOR_CODE
  1   ALUM          STAFF   
  8   ALUM          ALMG            STAF
```

What I need to be able to do is filter TEST_DATA before it gets pivoted. So if I only wanted to see IDs that had 'ALMG' how can I get a result set that looks like...

```
 ID   1_DONOR_CODE  2_DONOR_CODE    3_DONOR_CODE
  8   ALMG
```

Thanks.

Comment: why `'almg'` go to `1_donor` instead of `2_donor`?

Answer (score 1):

You could subquery the `TEST_DATA` table:

```
PIVOT_DATA AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM TEST_DATA
        WHERE DONOR_CODE = 'ALMG'
    )
    PIVOT (MAX(DONOR_CODE) AS DONOR_CODE FOR PRIORITY IN (1,2,3)
    )
)
SELECT * FROM PIVOT_DATA;
```

Comment: [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/OBYLI19981) I would use another cte, but same idea.

Comment: How could I pass ALMG from the actual SELECT? I won't know at design-time what values the user will choose. Ultimately the pivot CTE will be part of a view.

Comment: If you need dynamic behavior then a view probably isn't the way to go.  You should be able to do this via dynamic SQL in your app layer.